# VideoJS - no button works(page reload while click on any button)

Tags: html, video, html5-video, video.js

I am trying to use VideoJS on my site.

I try to follow instruction freom official site and copied to the `<head>` following code:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video.js"></script>
```

And into body following:

```
<video id="MY_VIDEO_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
       preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="http://www.ephotobay.com/image/birds-wallpaper-8-chai3721post.jpg"
       data-setup="{}">
    <source src="/member/createCompany/getVideo/1.flv"  type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="/member/createCompany/getVideo/1.flv" type='video/webm'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

Video plays good but noone button works(only play/stop button works):

[image]

When I click on red(on picture) button - page reloads

Can you advise me what do I wrong?
**P.S.**
[image: **P.S.**]

Comment: This doesn't happen with the video.js code alone. Try posting a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I agree with you but I cannot extract minimal example. I have a lot of dependencies